# sudo yum install postgresql doesn't work on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, yum, postgresql

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL on CentOS 7 (by following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-discourse-on-a-centos-6-4-x64-vps) to install Discourse) but when I give this command:

```
sudo yum install postgresql91-server.x86_64 postgresql91-contrib.x86_64 postgresql91-devel.x86_64
```

I get this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror base                                     | 3.6 kB  00:00:00 epel/x86_64/metalink                                |  24 kB  00:00:00 extras                                              | 3.4 kB  00:00:00 nginx                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00 http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found Trying other mirror. To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/



 One of the configured repositories failed (PostgreSQL 9.1 7 - x86_64),  and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only  safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable pgdg91

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=pgdg91.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pgdg91: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try. http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Any hint about how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To install PostgreSQL (64bit) on CentOS 7 ; run the following commands:

```
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-1.noarch.rpm
yum update
yum -y install postgresql96-server postgresql96-devel postgresql96-contrib
```

Initialize postgresql database:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
```

Start postgresql service and enable it at boot:

```
systemctl enable postgresql-9.6
systemctl start postgresql-9.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, from this page [PostgreSQL Repository Packages](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg91), find the version of PostgreSQL you want to install and copy the link.

Then, run this command with the link you copied:

```
#sudo yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
```

After that:

```
#sudo yum install -y postgresql95-server.x86_64 postgresql95-contrib.x86_64 postgresql95-libs.x86_64
#/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb
#sudo systemctl start postgresql-9.5.service
```

Also, if you want to start PostgreSQL on boot up:

```
#sudo systemctl enable postgresql-9.5.service
```